# How to divide the Circles into 24/7 equal parts using canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Growing Circles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="960" height="720"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( "c" ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

ctx.lineWidth = 3;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.fillStyle = "#4DA54D";
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = "DarkRed";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 120, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.strokeStyle = "OliveDrab";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 180, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.strokeStyle = "#530053";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 240, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.strokeStyle = "#208181";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 300, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.strokeStyle = "#CC7A00";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc( 500, 350, 360, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
ctx.strokeStyle = "#205450";
ctx.stroke();
```

I want to divide `This demo` into 24 hours timeline by using lines. I tried few but not up-to mark.It is going very big in code! 
Is there any other way to solve this in small piece of code like using slice as in `Tried demo` ?

[Tried Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CvnMw/14/)

**My Requirement** is to do as [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YNQ6v/10/).
I want to have `This demo` to be sliced 24/7 where 24 represent hours and 7 for days.

**Further Requirement** :: Even i must be able to access the `particular arc` which i want depending on the `day and hour` !

Finally i want to have a look like this [Image](http://photouploads.com/?v=capturoso.png) I will pass the arguments(Day, hour,Color) and then that particular segment should change the color, as i shown in the Image.

This is how i tried to print the numbers ..
`function drawnumbers(){ 
for(var i=1; i< hours+1;i++){
 context.font="18px sans-serif"; 
context.fillText(+i,20+i*30,20+i*30);
 }
}`but i want them on the outer circle as in png Image

Comment: It isn't completely clear, so do you want to have 7 segments, with each of those 7 segments to have 24 segments inside?

Comment: no i want to have 24 segments in each of my 7 circles ...(i have 7 circles as i gave in This demo) and i need each of them divided into 24 segments as i done in Tried demo.. @Neil

Comment: I want to have the 24 hours and 7 days in as like a pie chart to view a graph..

Comment: What's with the crazy upvotes? I mean, no offense OP, but really.

Comment: I need a help out @Pointy not satisfied with the upvotes!

Comment: Canvas is like popcorn here @Pointy :P

Comment: Well it's not a bad question, but it's a very specific problem. Anyway, I'm not sure what's wrong with that jsfiddle you linked. The circles get divided up like you ask. There are two almost-identical functions to draw the circles; those could be combined so you'd have one function that could draw as many circles as you need.

Comment: i'm unable to do that @Pointy it did not worked! all the colors and the widths are making me get confused more and more..

Comment: No big problem with your fiddle, as long as you draw circles from largest to smallest, use the radius parameter in your function, and use a color parameter http://jsfiddle.net/CvnMw/15/

Comment: @Pointy: The problem here is not that this question is too specific, but that it's sort of badly put, and quite clearly the dude is new to programming. And, I've noticed, votes on questions with canvas or twitter-bootstrap skyrocket quickly, no matter what the question is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [Harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630170/harsh) has already provided a very useful answer, it relates to the wireframe drawing which you depicted.

I thought it would also be useful to show you how you could achieve the drawing of the individual segments.

I think you have asked for a little too much in your PNG as we would practically be creating your project for you, but with my answer and Harsh's answer I believe you can get what you want:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// centre or center for US :) the drawing
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;

// number of days
var days = 7;

// number of hours
var hours = 24;

// one segment represents an hour so divide degrees by hours
var segmentWidth = 360 / hours;

// begin at 0 and end at one segment width
var startAngle = 0;
var endAngle = segmentWidth;

// how thick you want a segment
var segmentDepth = 30;

function init() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
        drawSegments(i * segmentDepth);
    }
}

function drawSegments(radius) {
    for (var i = 0; i < hours; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 
             (startAngle * Math.PI / 180), (endAngle * Math.PI / 180), false);
        context.lineWidth = segmentDepth;
        context.strokeStyle = '#' + 
             (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
        context.stroke();

        // increase per segment        
        startAngle += segmentWidth;
        endAngle += segmentWidth;
    }
}

// start drawing our chart
init();
```

See my http://jsfiddle.net/U2tPJ/6/ demo.

Comment: The Answer u gave works in completing the tasks of dividing the 7 circles into 24 equal parts .. but how can i access a particular segment inorder to change its color.

Comment: As in png.Image if i want to color the segment that is on sun and at the time of 1:00 hr..i had colored it with orange..so how to achieve this task in this –

Comment: I knew what u said is right but i'm in doubt of how to choose a particular segment if at all i had divided it using the loops as u did! i'm waiting for small clarification on this .. not that the answers given are worthless !

Comment: i accepted the answer and u see no one comes into help again that's y i kept it as unanswered before! i need a help out in how to get a particular segment to be selected to change its color..

Comment: @user2561626: It's actually very simple, but I would recommend you to do this on a piece of paper first: Start from any one segment in the inner circle, say the topmost one. Then mark each segment clock-wise as (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) ....

Comment: Now, for the next ring, mark segments as (1,1), (1,2), (1,3) and so on till you mark all segments. Each circle increases first index, and each segment in one circle increases the second index. Now, map indices 0-7 of circles to Sunday-Saturday.

Comment: @user2561626: With this explanation, I hope it strikes you. If it still doesn't, then you need to leave all this and start learning how to think as a programmer first, and then come back to this problem.

Comment: @Neil is there any way to display the text and numbers as i gave in the image... i tried with context.filltext(); but it doesnt fit correct for the Fiddle to view as in the png.image

Comment: @Neil i tried with this which prints the numbers.. but i want them around my outer circle as i shown in the png.image ..I tried `function drawnumbers(){
    for(var i=1; i< hours+1;i++){
    context.font="18px sans-serif";
    context.fillText(+i,20+i*30,20+i*30);
    }}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35408/discussion-between-harsh-and-user2561626)

Comment: @Harsh the [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35408/discussion-between-harsh-and-user2561626) is coming error

Comment: @Neil [This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3UJd/1/) once check it out.. i need this type of view, i knew what i did is only for one view,if at all i changed the dimensions everything again goes wrong so..please guide me..

Answer (score 6):

Man, you are doing *PROGRAMMING*, so why are you afraid of using the tools? Use loops and variables.

## Dial

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( "c" ),
ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" ),
strokes = ["DarkRed", "OliveDrab", "#530053", "#208181", "#CC7A00", "#205450"];
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( 500, 350, 420-60*i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
  if(i==6) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4DA54D";
    ctx.fill();
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokes[i];
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Now do the same for the 24 spokes (Use mathematical formulae)
// this is just from the top of my head, may need some adjustment
angle = 360/25; // you have 24 spokes, so 25 sectors (first and last one overlap or are the same)
for(var j=0; j<24; j++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(500, 350);
  ctx.lineTo(500+420*Math.sin(angle*j), 350-420*Math.cos(angle*j));
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

---

## Labels

For printing labels on the dial:

```
angle = 360/23;
for(var i=0; i<23; i++) {
  x = <centerX> + <radius> * Math.sin(angle*i*Math.PI/180) // convert from radian to angle
  y = <centerY> - <radius> * Math.cos(angle*i*Math.PI/180)
  context.fillText(i+1, x, y);
}
```

Comment: @user2561626: Check the updated code. Also note the use of 25 instead of 24 while calculating the separation angle.

Comment: Whilst this is a useful answer, it doesn't address the fact that the OP wanted filled areas as in his png image.

Comment: @Harsh The Answer u gave works in completing the tasks of dividing the 7 circles into 24 equal parts .. but how can i access a particular segment inorder to change its color..

Comment: @Harsh As in png.Image if i want to color the segment that is on sun and at the time of 1:00 hr..i had colored it with orange..so how to achieve this task in this

Comment: @user2561626: I knew this was coming up, but I had left it as an "excercise" for you to think upon.

Comment: @Harsh i tried with this which prints the numbers.. but i want them around my outer circle as i shown in the png.image ..I tried   `function drawnumbers(){ for(var i=1; i< hours+1;i++){ context.font="18px sans-serif"; context.fillText(+i,20+i*30,20+i*30); }}`

Comment: upto my understanding the Labels code will give labels but they will go in alternative way on the `dial` eg `(1,5,9,12,2,6,3,10,7,4,8,11,23,...)`, i want a sequence pattern like `1,2,3,4,...24..` on the `dial`.. once see the image it may give u better explanation if i'm not upto your mark..

Comment: @Harsh This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLtXa/1/) i cant make it work! sorry i'm new to canvas!

Comment: @Harsh  [This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3UJd/1/) once check it out.. i need this type of view, i knew what i did is only for one view,if at all i changed the dimensions everything again goes wrong so..please guide me.. – user2561626 just now

Comment: @user2561626: Oh, i'm sorry, It was my mistake. The `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` functions expect the argument to be in **radians** and not **degrees**, so you've got to convert that.

Comment: @user2561626: See my edited answer's Labels section. I'd already updated it with the corrected formulae.